# for loop, tuple out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, range

Not too sure what is causing this error
Using the Hackerrank 30 day challenge on day 5 and I can't seem to be able to change this so it'll work - I'm not too familiar with placeholders but have a basic understanding of how they work.

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys

n = int(input().strip())
for i in range(1, 10):
    answer = n * i
    print("{} x {} = {}".format((n, i, answer)))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 9, in <module>
    print("{} x {} = {}".format((n, i, answer)))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: `print("{} x {} = {}".format(n, i, answer))`

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input().strip())
for i in range(1, 10):
    answer = n * i
    print("{} x {} = {}".format(n, i, answer))  # changed here
```

You had a tuple for `n,i,answer` that was passed into `format()`. You just need to pass what you want to print and format into the function `format()`, no need to wrap it in a tuple.